# How to burn the bootloader onto a bare chip without using an Arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader

How do I burn the UNO bootloader onto ATMEGA328P-PU without using an Arduino Uno board. That is burn directly from my PC or Android device??

I've tried nothing, I don't know a thing about microcontrollers ☺

Comment: Start by using an AVR programmer (ex: USBasp from Ebay for a few bucks)  to burn the bootloader to an Arduino Uno or Nano first--so you can see the expected process and outcome, then try the standalone tutorial posted by MatsK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you need a **AVR programmer**

It is a tutorial on the Arduino website:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone

And the section *Bootloading your chips OPTIONAL* will answer the question.

Comment: A AVR programmer is aka ISP programmer